# BasicHttpBinding not using default configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, basichttpbinding

I have a web service running on ASP.NET 4.0 and have defined a default binding configuration for BasicHttpBinding in the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
...
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000" maxBufferSize="1024000"/>
   ...
  </basicHttpBinding>
  ...
 </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In one of my functions, I am instantiating a BasicHttpBinding object using the default constructor.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
```

I'm expecting it to take on the properties that I have defined in the default configuration, but it doesn't seem to be doing this. Instead, it's assigning the two values I defined in the default configuration (maxReceivedMessageSize, maxBufferSize) to 65536, which according to the Microsoft's documentation, is what they set as the default.

Do the default constructors not read from the web.config file? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell what to load
Web config Give a name to the binding

```
<system.serviceModel>
...
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding name="basicHttpBinding1">
   <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000" maxBufferSize="1024000"/>
   ...
  </basicHttpBinding>
  ...
 </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

C# 
   Call overload that accepts the name of the binding section

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding("basicHttpBinding1");
```